# How do I edit the partition boot record?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, mbr

I have a computer with 2 partitions, and I wanted to have Ubuntu on one partition (of 200GB) and Windows on the other(of 800GB), so I began installing windows on the 200GB one (by accident) I then realised that and installed windows also on the other partition. I then formatted the 200GB partition for Ubuntu and installed that. I thought all was okay, but when I now start my computer, it first shows me a choice between Ubuntu and Windows (which it should), but then I can choose between Windows 7 and Windows 7 (the first one is the one that really exists, when I try the other, it fails to boot and asks me to insert a windows CD. Now is my question, how can I edit that second list of Windows 7 and Windows 7, so it doesn't ask me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense that trying to boot into the second one does not work because you aborted the installation, so it does not have the Windows system files (only the boot-record).

You can boot into the good copy and remove the extraneous entry with [`BCDEDIT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667.aspx) (figure 1), [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (figure 2), or [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net/) (figure 3).

Just make sure that you are removing the correct one (double-check the drive-letter) otherwise you won’t be able to boot into Windows again until you use the Windows Recovery Environment (you can boot it from the DVD) to fix the boot options (figure 4).

---

**Figure 1**: `BCDEDIT`

[image]

**Figure 2**: EasyBCD

[image]

**Figure 3**: Visual BCD Editor

[image]

**Figure 4**: Windows Recovery

[image]